# Work with UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, delegates, dependencies

I have an `UIWebView`, which loads `HTML`-file from cache after initialization:

```
UIWebView *tempWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
tempWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tempWebView];

[tempWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
```

Than in `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` I'm trying to perform `javascript`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString] floatValue];
    // other manipulations...

    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The problem is that `HTML`-code has outer dependencies such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/book.css" type="text/css"/>
```

And there is such an impression, that this `*.css` has no time to load, so `javascript`-code returns a wrong value. If perform the content of `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` with delay (assume 2.0f secs), all will be fine.

But this delay may differ in different devices and situations. So how can I determine, that all dependencies are already loaded to perform my `javascript`-code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in

webViewDidStartLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString] floatValue];
// other manipulations...
}
```

Comment: It may help in delay for loading as you discussed for delay

Comment: I need t determine, whether all dependencies are loaded and perform js after that.